# Why $3\mid(5^{6n+6}-2^{2n+2})$ for all natural $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

How we can easily show that $3\mid(5^{6n+6}-2^{2n+2})$ for all natural $n$. These conditions continue $3\mid(5^{6n+5}-2^{2n+3})$ and $3\mid(5^{6n+4}-2^{2n+4})$ and $3\mid(5^{6n+3}-2^{2n+1})$ and $3\mid(5^{6n+2}-2^{2n+2})$ and $3\mid(5^{6n+1}-2^{2n+1})$.

Comment: You can use induction, note that for $n=k+1$:
$$5^{6k+12}-2^{2k+4}=5^6\cdot 5^{6k+6}-4\cdot 2^{2k+2}=4(5^{6k+6}-2^{2k+2})+(5^6-4)\cdot 5^{6k+6}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
5^{6n+6}-2^{2n+2} &\equiv 2^{6n+6}-2^{2n+2} \pmod{3} \\
&\equiv  2^{2n+2}(2^{(2n+2)2}-1) \pmod{3}\\
&\equiv2^{2n+2}(1-1) \pmod{3}\\
&\equiv 0 \pmod{3}
\end{align}

Notice that I used  $\gcd(3, 2^{2n+2})=1$ and Fermat's theorem to conclude that $2^{(2n+2)2}\equiv1 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: You also use Fermat's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

By binomial theorem$$5^{6n+6}-2^{2n+2}$$
$$={(3+2)}^{6n+6}-2^{2n+2}$$
$$=3k+2^{6n+6}-2^{2n+2}$$
$$=3k+2^{2n+2}({(3-1)}^{4n+4}-1)=3k+2^{2n+2}(3m)$$

Answer (score 0):

$5^{6n}-2^{2n}=125^{2n}-2^{2n}$

$=(125-2)\left(125^{2n-1}+125^{2n-2}2+125^{2n-3}2^2+\cdots+125^22^{2n-3}+125\cdot2^{2n-2}+2^{2n-1}\right)$

is divisible by $3$, because $125-2$ is.

Now substitute $m=n+1$ to show that $5^{6m+6}-2^{2m+2}$ is divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

we have 
 $5^2 \equiv 1\ (mod\ 3) \Rightarrow 5^{2(3n+3)} \equiv 1\ (mod\ 3) \Rightarrow 5^{6n+6} \equiv 1\ (mod\ 3) $

and we have 
$2^2 \equiv 1\ (mod\ 3) \Rightarrow 2^{2(n+1)} \equiv 1\ (mod\ 3) \Rightarrow 2^{2n+2} \equiv 1\ (mod\ 3) $ 
 Thus 
 $$5^{6n+6}-2^{2n+2} \equiv 0\ (mod\ 3)$$